# Is there a way to pass in custom command-line arguments to Brunch?

Tags: node.js, command-line-arguments, brunch, build-tools

I'm trying to pass in custom command-line arguments to brunch, something like this:

```
brunch build -p myCustomArg
```

But no matter what I input it throws an error:

```
path\graceful-fs\polyfill.js:18
chdir.call(process, d)

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, uv_chdir
```

At least I'm guessing it's attempting to "**make sense**" of the custom arguments I'm passing, but fails to identify them so it aborts.

Are there any special arguments (like `--`, like how [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/6ccb29864c7a17b578a5a09b9a2dd382bbb41066/doc/cli/help.txt#L21) has one) to separate the brunch specific arguments from the rest?

Comment: Added a pull-request with an attempt to bring this support (via a `--` argument). https://github.com/brunch/brunch/pull/1296

Comment: Have you solve this problem yet?
I have the sabe issue.

Comment: I can't remember exactly what I did, but I think I ended up forking the project and patching it up to accept an `--` argument to pass whatever follows it as extra options. I think it was in it's "commander.js" file or something like that.